# WP Twenty Twelve Header Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've recently downloaded the latest version of Wordpress and I'm working on developing a child-theme off of the new [Twenty Twelve](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/twentytwelve/).

When a user uploads a header image, its default styling is to place a 1px solid #d2d2d2 border around it, give it a 3px border-radius, a box-shadow and align it to the left.

As simple as this may sound I would like to keep this, but center align the header images instead and place a 1px solid #ededed line 32px below it (this line should extend to 100% of the sites width, so even if the header images are small, the line will continue passed the uploaded image to each side of the wrapper).

For some reason, I cannot target the right HTML and CSS rules to achieve this.

I've tried a number of things, from playing around with the header.php and /inc/custom-header.php files, modifying properties and placing at the very bottom of my style.css document:
`header img, header img a, header a img, .header-image {`

`text-align: center; margin: inherit auto; padding-bottom: 32px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;`
`}`

`header img:after, header img a:after, header a img:after, .header-image:after {` 
`border-bottom: 4px solid red; padding-bottom: 32px;` 
`}`

How would I achieve this desired effect for when the user uploads a header image?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own questions. =) If you want to remove it, remove it.

Comment: I 2nd that statment. Editing the question to a empty question is no way to remove it from the site please try and keep this site pretty.

Comment: There should be a "Delete"-link right in the same line as "share | edit" etc.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want it removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line 442 of your style.css:

```
.header-image {
    display block;
    margin: 0 auto 2em;
}
```

Comment: * facepalm* - `display: block;` thank you.

Any ideas on creating the line below it?

Comment: You can display the anchor tag containing the header image as a block and add a border bottom to that anchor tag then just adjust the margins. Like http://s10.postimage.org/o2ewew3vd/illuminada2.jpg